# Implementing natural numbers

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm new to Haskell and functional-programming. I'm trying to implement Natural numbers with functions and a "plus" function. I have a given type that can't be changed.

```
type Number t = (t -> t) -> t -> t
```

Therefor I have to implement a "zero" function that represents number 0, a "next"
function that returns next number and a "plus" function.

```
zero :: Number t
zero x = ???

next :: Number t -> Number t
next n = \f z -> ???

plus :: Number t -> Number t -> Number t
plus x y = ???
```

After implementing those I should be able to test this:

```
one :: Number t
one = next zero
tesOne = one (+ 1) 0

two :: Number t
two = plus (next zero) (next zero)
testTwo = (+ 5) 0
```

In this code "testOne" should be 1 and "testTwo" should be 10. 
Thank you for taking time to look !

I tried this, but i guess i don't quite understand functional-programming yet.

```
zero :: Number t
zero x = (\f ->f) x


next :: Number t -> Number t
next n = \f z -> f z

plus :: Number t -> Number t -> Number t
plus x y = (\f x y -> x + y) x y
```

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding

Comment: What thoughts have you had about the problem? What have you tried? Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Try with `zero f x = x` and `next n f x = f (n f x)`

Answer (score 4):

Thank you Evan and Bergi, after reading Church encoding, I found the answer.

```
zero :: Number t
zero f x = x

next :: Number t -> Number t
next n f x = f (n f x)

plus :: Number t -> Number t -> Number t
plus m n f x = m f (n f x)
```